# How to put parameters into a for loop from a txt file read with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, text-files, readfile

I don't know how to use pandas in this context. I have my dataset :[How can I read specific colums from a txt file in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51431017/how-can-i-read-specific-colums-from-a-txt-file-in-python][1]).

What I want to do is to take artists and tracks and put them into a "for" to make a Spotify request. I don't know what to put after "for i in". Sorry for my ignorance.

```
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('playlist1.txt', sep='\t', header=None, names=['artists', 'tracks'], usecols=[3, 4])

for i in [????]:
    artist_name = df.artists[i]
    track_name = df.tracks[i]
    q = artist_name + ", " + track_name
    search=spotify.search(q, limit=1, type="track,artist")
       for i in range (0,limit):
          if (search["tracks"]["items"]) <> []:
            array_id.append(search["tracks"]["items"][i]["id"].encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
```

Comment: you could use e.g. `df.iterrows()`. [A similiar question exists here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a self contained example with a 3 row data set.  Please pardon my taste in music.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO("""
artists,tracks
U2,War
Maroon 5,Girls Like You
Ed Sheeran,Perfect
""")

df = pd.read_csv(data)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    q = row['artists'] + ", " + row['tracks']
    print(q)
```

which prints:

```
U2, War
Maroon 5, Girls Like You
Ed Sheeran, Perfect
```